# Barra de búsqueda con tablas relacionadas muchos a muchos

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Tengo la tabla llamada **COIN** con los campos ***id*** y ***name***, también tengo una tabla llamada **EVENT** con los campos ***id, title, description***. En mi proyecto, una coin puede tener muchos event y un event puede tener muchas coin relacionados, por lo tanto hice una tabla intermedia llamada ***coin_event***. La pregunta es ¿como puedo hacer una barra de búsqueda que al seleccionar desde el **Select2** las coin que quiero, me devuelva todos los **eventos relacionados** con los coin seleccionados?

Solamente tengo el controlador PageController el cual tendrá el método que haga lo que necesito, pero hasta el momento estoy en pañales y no sé por donde partir.

Ocupo laravel 5.6

Event Model

```
public function coins()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Coin::class);
}
```

Coin_event migration

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('coin_event', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('coin_id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('event_id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Coin Model

```
public function events()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Event::class);
}
```

PageController

```
public function search(Request $request){

    $coins = Coin::findMany($request->coinSearch)->load('events')
               ->orderBy('event_at', 'DESC')
               ->where('status', 'APROBADO')
               ->paginate(8);
    $events = $coins->pluck('events')->collapse();
    return view('welcome', compact('events', 'coins'));
}
```

Welcome view

```
<form name="form" method="get" class="form" role="form"
      action="{{ route('search') }}">
   {{csrf_field()}}
   <div class="form-group">
      <select class="select2 select-coin col-12 form-control" 
              id="coinSearch"
              name="coinSearch[]"
              multiple="multiple"
              style="width: 260px;"
              required>
              @foreach ($coins as $coin)
                <option value="{{ $coin->id }}">{{ $coin->coin_name }} 
                </option>
              @endforeach
            </select>
            <button class="btn btn-rounded btn-info">Buscar</button>
         </div>
       </form>
```

Ejemplo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Código de lo que has intentando?

Comment: @Tristian, este es todo el código de esa sección, no sé como lograr el objetivo